# Powershell to delete all files except some meeting special date criteria

Tags: powershell

I've a scenario. Before moving to that, let me say I need a logic as well from here. I've tried something (which I will tell shortly), but that doesnt seems to be working.

I've some files which is getting created each hour. I am scripting (powershell) to delete those in the way given below:

Out of 24 files created in a day, I need to keep only 1 (which is the last and latest created, need to delete other 23) daily for an entire week. This is DONE.

**Now, on a weekly basis I need to do this in such a way that every saturday night, I need to delete 6 daily files and retain the latest one (of day 7). I am stuck here.**

What I've tried is like using $date.AddDays(-1) which is okay for the first week. Second week, I need to retain last week's (1) file and need to retain this week's (1) file. So, here I am running out of logic.

In the same scenario I need to have it monthly also. I think I can get this done if I get some logic for weekly (which is in **Bold**).

Can anyone please help me at the earliest. Any suggestions or thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: sort your file by lastwritetime -desc and remove all except first file

Comment: @Kayasax: I am afraid that I can't do that. I need to retain my last week file as well. If I go as you said, I may end up deleting all files except of today.

Comment: As a temporary solution, you can just move/copy the file to be retained to another folder, and then leave one file in this folder.

Comment: Would you not just remove the files that were created between a day ago and a week ago? Since you have removed all the other hourly files for that time?

Comment: Can I anyhow do something like calculate every saturday's date of that executing month and see if any files exist on those dates. If exists, retain else nothing. Can this be done?

Comment: @Matt: On third week of a month, I may have 2 week files + 7 days (of current week) files making it to a total of 9 files. I need to retain 2 week files + todays file making it to a count of 3.

Comment: The weekly files that exist are all from the same day of the week? You can filter based on that and even a time since it _appears_ you are removing everything else.

Comment: To list files created on saturdays `ls *.* |select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime |?{ $_.dayofweek -match "saturday"}  `

Comment: @Kayasax that is the logic I am trying to describe but that will just show the times and not the files will it not?

Comment: @Matt: Suppose in a week starting from 1-7, I will have a final file saved on 7th. From 8-14, saved on 14th. So, in a week from 15-21, I need to save files of date 7, 14 and 21.

Comment: ok this one so : `ls *.* |select name, lastwritetime |?{ $_.lastwritetime.dayofweek -match "saturday"}`

Comment: Ok then..... are those dates the same or is there no pattern for when a week starts?

Comment: Depending on when the actual week for a month starts. Anyway we'll make the script to execute every saturdays.

Comment: this is better : `ls *.* |?{ $_.lastwritetime.dayofweek -match "monday"} |select -expand name  `

Comment: @Matt saturdays are not always the 7th day of the month

Comment: 7,14,21 are just assumed dates. If the first week for a month starts on Wednesday, then there are only 4 days in that week (till saturday).

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. Explain what you expect it do do, and describe what it actually does. Examples of which files you want retained/deleted would be helpful. Also explain how you intend to run it (since this seems to be for some kind of scheduled job(s)).

Comment: Alright... now I think I'm getting it.... The saturdays of everymonth are known though so you just need to calculate those and use that logic for deletion ommition correct?

Comment: Exactly. As I said, I just need to calculate dates of every saturday on a month and omit the files which are created or which has timestamp on their name on that date.?

Comment: So have you tried what Kayasax wrote then which is what I was suggesting? You just need to use -notmatch instead and other clauses for times and current month if required?

Comment: Ok, will try that. Just to understand don't we have a way to calculate dates of all saturday on a month?

Comment: Yes that of course is possible but why would you need that information if you can just compare the day of week?

Comment: Same kind of thing (but reading from a file) has to be done with another script. And that requires this calculation. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forigve me if I got lost in all the comments but you could use this to get all the dates in the *current* month that are saturdays.

```
$now = Get-date
1..[DateTime]::DaysInMonth($now.Year,$now.Month) | ForEach-Object{get-date -day $_} | Where-Object{$_.DayOfWeek -eq "Saturday"}
```

So for July 2015

```
Saturday, July 04, 2015 8:22:53 AM
Saturday, July 11, 2015 8:22:53 AM
Saturday, July 18, 2015 8:22:53 AM
Saturday, July 25, 2015 8:22:53 AM
```

Of course you might want just the days so we can just add to the end of this. `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Day`.

```
4
11
18
25
```

You can now use those values in you date exclusion logic. Which could be useful if you are trying to compare dates ahead of time. Still PowerShell already has logic to caluculates individual dates to see if they are "saturday". So like [Kayasax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381149/kayasax) was suggetsting

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | Where-Object{ $_.lastwritetime.dayofweek -notmatch "saturday"} |select-object -expandproperty fullname
```

And add other date logic for hour or what not as required.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother calculate anything? Takes advantage of powershell's power :) !
Get a date (from a file, from a var, or whatever) cast it do datetime and display the dayOfWeek property

```
([system.datetime]"09/07/2015").DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the logic of the part you have already built, which is to group together files that were created in the same day, and retain only the latest file out of each group.  This undoubtedly depends on converting the timestamp of the file's creation into a date.

What you need is a function, call it "week" which, given a date, returns the week number.  So, for dates from Jul-5-2015 through Jul-11-2015, it might return the number "27", meaning the 27th week of the year.

Now create logic similar to the logic of what you have already built.  But, instead of grouping by day, group by week number.

If you intend to keep this data for more than a year, you need to do something like the first week of next year returns "53".

Comment: If you were grouping by months, you could use the Month property of a date,  as in $some_date.Month